# How to convert object to image and store image locally in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

Hello i am trying to convert object to image and i want to store that image and bind to html element.When i am loading local image it is working properly.How to convert object to image.I am trying to write code

```
 on(State, 'update-end', function () {

        esriRequest({
            "url": StateUrl,
            "content": {
                "f": "json"
            },
            "callbackParamName": "callback"
        }).
   then(function (evt) {
       var graphicstmp = evt.drawingInfo.renderer.symbol.outline;
       var stateOutLine = new SimpleLineSymbol(graphicstmp);

       var stateimg = localStorage.setItem("stateOutLine", stateOutLine);
       var dataImage = localStorage.getItem('stateOutLine');
       var x = document.getElementById('symbolState').setAttribute('src', 'dataImage');

       document.getElementById("symbolState").innerHTML = x;
       console.log(graphicstmp);
       alert(stateOutLine);
   });

});
```

console output is

```
color

    [0, 115, 76, 255]
style

    "esriSLSSolid"
type

    "esriSLS"
width

    1.7
```

Comment: What is the value you get in `graphicstmp`? Depending on that you will need to set the `src` attribute or the `background` attribute.

Comment: Hello i Updated my question with console output.

Comment: Like i mentioned before, what is the value of `graphicstmp`? This is more of a debugging issue. Please check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) for what the `src` attribute expects. Assuming `document.getElementById('symbolState')` is an `img` tag

Comment: The value for graphicstmp is color input array of values.color[0,115,76,255]

Comment: Please check the documentation link mentioned in the previous comment. The `src` attribute takes a URL, it will not work with numbers.

Comment: Yes you are correct and irealized that.i want to convert that color to image format.is there any possible way to convert to image.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way to do that. I think you need to look at how the `arcgis-js-api` actually works.

Comment: ok thank you.I am trying to get solution for this problem.